# Newline not working correctly when using with console.log styling in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, console.log

I hope I'm not doing something daft but I'm writing this out in the devtools in Chrome:

```
console.log('%c{\n  a: %c1 %c2%c,\n}', 'color:grey;', 
    'color:red;', 'color:green;', 'color:grey;');
```

and I would expect to see this:

```
{
    a: 1 2,
}
```

But actually I get this:

```
{      ,
 a: 1 2 }
```

Which makes absolutely no sense to me...?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems like all styled texts in console are some kind of inline-blocks, stacked side-by-side.

So, in fact, if we'll add background-color to your code, we'll be able to see the true layout of your text:

[image: actual layout]

So, to get the image, that you want, it seems like you have to consider this "column-based" layout. For your example, it would be:

```
console.log('%c{\n  a: \n}%c1\n  %c2\n %c,\n ', 'color: grey;', 'color: red;', 'color:green;', 'color:grey;');
```

Here is the result of above code:

[image: expected image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution, to make them stack as blocks, instead of inline-blocks. So, it seems like your only option is to use `console.log()` for each line. If it's critical for you to generate one line - you can write a function to split this line by `\n` character and `console.log()` each part of the string.

**UPDATE**
Bug in Chrome is fixed, OP's code works as expected now in Chrome 89.0.4389.90

Comment: Thank you, that is what I've resorted to doing at the moment but it seems very odd that no-one seems to have come across or mentioned this before.  It is not in the chrome developer tools documentation either.

Comment: This hasn't be mentioned before because it used to work as expected but there is currently a bug in the formatting giving the results shown.

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin2, it's valuable information. Is there any bug report regarding this?

Comment: I'm also curious to know of any bug report for this. It was working for me a couple of weeks ago but now it seems broken. Side note: Firefox handles my console.logs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a similar problem trying to log mulitple properties of an object in a single console.log statement but styled in several lines.

I wanted to log properties in ***name --> value*** format and also having the value coloured in red to make easier to read.

So what I finally built was this function:

```
//Function to transform an object to a formated string and params
var generateColouredLogObject = obj => {
    var formatedString = ""
    var arrayParams = []

    Object.keys(obj)
        .map(key => {
            obj[key]
                .map(item => {
                    formatedString += "%c %s --> %c %s %c"
                    arrayParams.push("", item.tag, "color:red", item.value, "")
                })
            formatedString += " \n"
        })

    return {text: formatedString, params: arrayParams}
}
```

This way an object like this:

```
//the data we want to print 
//Its built one 'line' property as an array containing each of the items (pair tag-vaule) you want to print
var objToLog = {
    line1: [{ tag: "domain", value: window.document.domain }],
    line2: [{ tag: "protocol", value: window.document.location.protocol }, { tag: "pahtname", value: window.document.location.pathname }],
}
```

produces an output like this when execute this code:

```
var output = generateColouredLogObject(objToLog)

console.log(output.text, ...output.params)
```

[Dev Console output when executing code on this same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMFro.png)

For your example you should build the "formatedString" and "arrayParams" adapted to your scenario

Hope it helps